# Create new object with a selection of items

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, variables

```
myObject  { orange: "10.5", banana:"20.5", apple: "5.1", pineapple: "5.1", cherry: "5.1" }
```

I'd like to create this

```
myNewObject { apple: "5.1", cherry: "5.1" }
```

My code is

```
for (var property in myObject)  {
delete object["orange"];
delete object["banana"];
delete object["pineapple"];
}
```

)
Is there a function contrary to the delete function ? I'd like to declare in an array the selection of items that I keep in myNewObject

```
var FruitsRed = ["apple", "cherry",]
```

Comment: Check out .map()

Comment: `contrary to delete` you mean adding a property?

Comment: `for (var property in myObject  {` is an error

Comment: Why can you not just reassign the variable?

Comment: Why do you even loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of the properties that you want, and use `.map()` to create a list of objects, which are then passed to `Object.assign()`.

```js
var myObject = {orange: "10.5", banana: "20.5", apple: "5.1", pineapple: "5.1", cherry: "5.1"};

var res = Object.assign({}, 
   ...["banana", "cherry"].map(s => ({[s]: myObject[s]}))
);

console.log(res);
```

---

Or if you actually wanted to ***mutate*** the original object like your first example, then you can iterate over all the keys and delete ones that are not in a pre-defined set.

```js
var myObject = {orange: "10.5", banana: "20.5", apple: "5.1", pineapple: "5.1", cherry: "5.1"};
var toKeep = new Set(["banana", "cherry"]);

Object.keys(myObject)
      .filter(k => !toKeep.has(k))
      .forEach(k => delete myObject[k]);

console.log(myObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the functions `filter`, `includes` and `reduce`.

```js
var FruitsRed = ["apple", "cherry"],
    myObject = { orange: "10.5", banana:"20.5", apple: "5.1", pineapple: "5.1", cherry: "5.1" },
    myNewObject = Object.keys(myObject)
                        .filter(k => FruitsRed.includes(k))
                        .reduce((a, k) => ({ ...a, ...{[k]: myObject[k]}}), {});


console.log(myNewObject);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use object ES6 destructuring.

```js
let myObject = { orange: "10.5", banana:"20.5", apple: "5.1", pineapple: "5.1", cherry: "5.1" };

let { orange, banana, pineapple, ...myNewObject } = myObject;
console.log(myNewObject);
```

Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop over your array and build up your new object as you go.

```js
var obj = { orange: "10.5", banana:"20.5", apple: "5.1", pineapple: "5.1", cherry: "5.1" }
    
var FruitsRed = ["apple", "cherry",]
var newObj = {}
FruitsRed.forEach(function (fruit) {
    newObj[fruit] = obj[fruit];
});
console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the array and get the desired key-value pair:

```js
var myObject = { "orange": "10.5", "banana":"20.5", "apple": "5.1", "pineapple": "5.1", "cherry": "5.1" };
var myNewObject = {};
var FruitsRed = ["apple", "cherry"];

FruitsRed.forEach(function(fruit){
   myNewObject[fruit] = myObject[fruit];
});

console.log(myNewObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let myObject  = { orange: "10.5", banana:"20.5", apple: "5.1", pineapple: "5.1", cherry: "5.1" }
let FruitsRed = ["apple", "cherry",]
Object.keys(myObject).forEach((k)=> FruitsRed.indexOf(k)===-1 && delete myObject[k])
```

let me know if this works